# Ruby: How to incorporate multithreading into this web-scraping scenario?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, http, parsing, web-scraping

I have a list of folders which contain lots of text files. 
Inside those files are links.

Using each one of those links, I will need to fetch a webpage, parse it, and depending on what's there - save a JPG file into a folder corresponding to the folder name that contains the text file that provided the link.

Now the catch is that there's a LOT of text files and even more links inside of them. I was thinking that it may not be such a bad idea to multithread the process of connecting to and parsing webpages.

So I'll have something like this:

```
directories.each do |directory|

 ... 

 all_files_in_directory.each do |file|

  ...

  all_urls_in_file do |url|

   # check if there's any threads that aren't busy
   # make a thread go out to the url and parse it

  end

 end


end
```

I'm a bit unsure how to do that if it's even possible - I can't seem to find a way to have threads just sort of hang out until I tell them some_method() to execute. It's as if what a thread does is assigned to it upon creation and cannot be changed.

So basically I want the script to be able to connect and parse, say, in batches of 5 instead of just 1.

Is this doable, and if so, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: Well, you are correct in that you should get a big speedup.  Web crawling is riddled with IO waits for DNS lookup, TCP connect etc.  A large dollop of threads should get a lot more done much more quickly.

Comment: You should fid a Ruby implementation that is multithreading-friendly.  Some are better than others, aparrently, though it seems to not matter that much with IO-boud apps like yours - it's more of an issue with CPU-bound apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider eventmachine and [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request) for concurrent http requests.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, such activities are performed by queueing 'task' objects to a pool of threads that are waiting on a producer-consumer 'pool queue'.  Each thread loops around forever, pulling tasks off the queue and calling a virtual 'run' method of the task.  Usually, if they wish, tasks can create more tasks and submit them to the pool queue.

Different 'task' class descendants can have a run() method that does different things & so, even though the thread is indeed 'doing what was assigned to it upon creation' - that something means hanging about on a queue and then, when tasks are available, caling different overridden methods in different tasks.

Flow control, right. Make a batchURL' task class that can hold 'batch size' urls. At start, create.. say.. 100 of them and push them onto an 'objectQueue', (a producer-consumer queue class like the pool queue). In your readline loop, pop a batchURL, load it up with urls and submit it to the pool queue. When a pool thread has done with a batchURL, push it back onto the objectQueue for re-use. This puts a cap on the outstanding batchURLs - if the readLine tries to queue up too many batchURLs, it will find the objectQueue empty and so wil block until some batchURLs are recycled by the pool.

If you use a reasonable number of batchSIze, batchURLs and threads, the batchURLs should happily circulate around the objectQueue/workThead/poolQueue loop, carrying the data around from your readLine to the work threads in an efficient and effective manner.

Comment: Can you give a quick example or point me to a resource where I can see some examples? When I google "task" all I see is rails' Rake task stuff.

Comment: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3276 << I found this which seems sort of what you're talking about. Except the way that my program is constructed, the readline loop will read through all 100,000 lines or so and add them all to the thread pool, likely with scary consequences. Do you see what I'm saying? How do I augment the program to only add to the th read pool in "batches"?

Comment: Oh, I looked at the 'snippets' link for the pool.  It's not nice.  It's got a sleep() loop in it :(